# Save data in express session

Tags: node.js, express

I would need to save some token in express session. So, I would need help how to save this token in session object.
Any example would be more helpful.

Also is it a good practice to save such information in session object or do I need to use some persistent storage like redis cache DB.

Comment: You need to be more precise with the second part of your question. Also show us what you've tried so far (using available resources) and what the outcome was.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can store a token in the session. This is generally done as follows:

```
app.use(session({
      token : your_token_value
    })
}));
```

Or, as an alternative way:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var sessData = req.session;
  sessData.token = your_token_value;
  res.send('Returning with some text');
});
```

Regarding the storage place. It is a kind of a different layer under the session. The values which you store in the session can be placed in different locations: in the application memory, in memcache, a database or in cookies.

For production you can use Memory Cache. For instance, https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached:

It can be achieved as follows:

```
app.use(session({
      token : your_token_value,
      key     : 'test',
      proxy   : 'true',
      store   : new MemcachedStore({
        hosts: ['127.0.0.1:11211'], //this should be where your Memcached server is running
        secret: 'memcached-secret-key' // Optionally use transparent encryption for memcache session data 
    })
}));
```